# What is the key for outgoing number?

Tags: android

I had seen

```
String phoneNr= bundle.getString("incoming_number");
```

where "incoming_number" is the key for incoming call number bundled in the Intent of  Broadcast receiver received in onReceive method of Broadcast receiver.

then What is the key for the outgoing / dialed number?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't hard-code any string keys.  If you're building a broadcast receiver for outgoing calls, you can use

```
String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
```

in your `onReceive` method.

Comment: Did you declare it in manifest?  And did you request correct permission?

Comment: actually I am able to get the incoming number... should I have to to anything more to get the out going number

Comment: What incoming number?? You need two completely separate broadcast receivers - one for incoming, one for outgoing.

Comment: <receiver android:name="com.example.testappNew.OutgoingReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: I think I missed this receiver right Aleks
<action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>

Comment: @donison24x7 Exactly.  You need to declare your receiver with that action.  You also need to declare the permission to see outgoing calls.

Answer (score 0):

Those values are custom. You call them whatever you want to, when you do bundle.putString("myKey", "myValue"); 
It depends on the kind of Intent you are reading the bundle from.